# Combine Tab,Navigation Controller and View Controllers

Tags: ios

I have created a Tabbed Application with 4 tabs and 4 viewControllers for each tab.I try to add Navigation bar in FirstViewController,it adds navigation bar only,the content area display as black.

- How to combine Navigation controller,Tab and view Controller?
- What are the possible ways of combine ViewControllers?

**My Tab and View Controllers code:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3, *viewController4;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    } else {
        viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    }
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, viewController4];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I added viewController1 inside a navigationController and add this navigationController object to tabBarController. Now It works fine. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015122/combining-navigation-controller-with-tab-bar-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *secondNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];


    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3, *viewController4;
      if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  firstNav.viewControllers =  @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, viewController4];

} else {
    viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    secondNav.viewControllers =  @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, viewController4];
}
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstnav, secondNav];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I added viewController1 inside a navigationController and add this navigationController object to tabBarController. Now It works fine. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030551/1119440

```
UIViewController *tmpviewController1, *viewController2,*viewController3, *viewController4;
        UINavigationController *viewController1;


        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

            //UIViewController *tmpViewController1 = [[[YourViewController alloc] init] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
            tmpviewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            viewController1 =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tmpviewController1];

            //viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        } else {
            viewController1 = [[VKFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
            viewController2 = [[VKSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
            viewController3 = [[VKThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
            viewController4 = [[VKFourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VKFourthViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

        }
        self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3, viewController4];
```